Unable to remove Log using assumeNoSideEffect with Dexguard
I'm trying to remove Android's Log methods using Dexguard, but I'm not able to do this.
This is what I'm doing:
build.gradle(:app)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'

android {

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = rootProject.javaSourceCompatibility
        targetCompatibility = rootProject.javaTargetCompatibility
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
        buildConfig = true
    }


   

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion xx
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        versionName COMMON_VERSION_NAME


    }


    flavorDimensions = ["deploymentType"]

    productFlavors {
        local {
            isDefault = true
            dimension "deploymentType"
        }

        mavenRelease {
            dimension "deploymentType"
        }

        mavenDevelopment {
            dimension "deploymentType"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        stagingStable {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, IS_DEBUG, TRUE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, IS_STAGING_STABLE, TRUE
            matchingFallbacks = ['development', 'release']
        }

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpVersion"
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
}

dexguard {
    path = '../../dexguard/DexGuard-9.5.5/'
    license = 'dexguard/dexguard-license.txt'

    configurations {
       localStagingStable{
            defaultConfiguration 'dexguard-release.pro'
            configuration 'dexguard/dexguard-release-sdk.txt'
        }
        
    }
}

where in the proguard-rules.pro
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /home/mateobosco/Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Remove Android logging calls (in this case, including errors).
-optimizations code/removal/*

-assumenosideeffects public class android.util.Log

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }

and dexguard-release-sdk.txt
# We'll display some more statistics about the processed code.
-verbose

# Base rules
-include ../../../dexguard/dexguard-rules.pro

# Print a full report
-printconfiguration ../build/fullconfig.pro


# Encrypt the "geopagos" classes
#-encryptclasses com.geopagos.**
#-encryptclasses com.model.geopagos.**
#-encryptclasses com.services.geopagos.**
#-encryptclasses com.utils.geopagos.**

-optimizations code/removal/*

-assumenosideeffects public class android.util.Log

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }

I create an apk using "assemble" command, and then install in my phone, but I'm still seeing the logs. What am I doing wrong?

What logs? The Log class is not the only way to write to logcat, don't forget System.out.println() and similar. To make sure if Log statement had been removed decompile your APK e.g. using Jadx-Gui then you will see if Dexguard config was effective.

@Robert, The one im using is Log.d.

That's probably not an exact duplicate, but the desired outcome is just the same... just "search in files" for Log.d an wrap them, in order to make it log conditionally; these lines assumedly will then be optimized away all by itself. Unhandled expections will still be logged.
